# Implementing Dark mode on Legacy Android Project

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, darkmode, android-darkmode

I have a feature requirement to implement dark mode in my old Legacy project which uses a mixture of AppCompact Activities and normal Activities and is roughly more than 1500 files.

I want to ask if there is an automated way or a utility that can handle the basic functionality of conversion. I know I would need to do some manual work for like icons and pictures But is there a way to automate the textual change from light to dark?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force-dark

Comment: you can specify your styles in respect themes files. so that it takes the style as per the mode of the screen and display it accordingly. simply i can say by using the themes.xml we can achieve this whatever you are expecting..

Answer (score 0):

Using The DayNight functionality in AppCompat, you can quickly convert your app to adapt to Dark Mode theme dynamically without much code changes, did that successfully to a number of apps.
See more instructions on this site here:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94